# Предзагрузка больших изображений на сайте

Tags: jquery, изображения, javascript

Есть большая галерея изображений, большинство из них скрыто и показывается по некоторым событиям. И при срабатывании этих событий видно, как подгружаются изображения, чего хотелось бы избежать, т.к. пользователь "дойдёт" до этой галереи только через промежуток времени, в котрый можно постараться подгрузить изображения.

CMS отдаст массив, что-то вроде:

```
var __imagePreloader = ['/path/to/image.png', '/path/to/image.png', '/path/to/image.png', '/path/to/image.png', '/path/to/image.png'];
```

Если я обработаю таким образом его на (событие document.ready или window.load?):

```
myApp {
   'imagePreload':function(imgArray){
        imgArray = imgArray || false;
        if (!imgArray) { return false; }

        $.each(imgArray,function(i,thisImg){
              var tempImg = new Image();
              tempImg.src = thisImg;
        }
        return true;
   }
};

$(document).ready(){
    myApp.imagePreload(__imagePreloader);
});
```

"Скеширует" ли это чудо изображение? Корректна ли данная реализация?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, "Скеширует".